# Hibernate realiza consultas no deseadas (@ManyToOne)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Tengo una entidad A vinculada a B con una relación ManyToOne, de tipo Lazy

```
public class A extends BaseEntity {

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TipoTurnoEnum tipo;

private String number;
private String state;
private Date date;

@JoinColumn(name = "id_b", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private B b; 
/* Se excluye el resto de la entidad */
```

Cuando realizo una consulta sobre la entidad A, y en el resultado el atributo B no es nulo, Hibernate realiza una segunda consulta, esta vez sobre B.

i.e.:

```
2018-10-09 14:51:32.176 DEBUG 15484 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
select
    A.numero as numero1_1_,
    A.estado as estado2_1_,
    A.fecha as fecha3_1_,
    A.b as b7_1_ 
from
    A
where
    A.numero=?
```

Si A.b no es nulo, entonces Hibernate ejecuta:

```
select
    B.id as id1_15_0_,
    B.descripcion as descripcion_15_0_
from
    B
where
    B.id=?
```

Siendo ? en B.id, reemplazado por el valor de A.b obtenido en la primera consulta.
El objeto request que paso como filtro de el frontend (typescript) fue definido como:

```
let request = {
    A: {number: 1}
};
```

¿Cómo evito que Hibernate haga esto?
¿Por qué sucede esto incluso cuando la relación está explicitamente definida como Lazy?
Solo me interesan los valores de A, excepto cuando envío un atributo para filtrar B, es decir:

```
A: {
    number: 1, 
    b: {
        id: 2
    }
}
```

Estoy utilizando la función findOne de crudRepository (invocandose desde la interface genericRepository)

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/findOne", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public BaseEntity findone(@RequestBody FiltroRequest request) throws GenericException {

    return genericService.findOne(request);
}
```

Muchas gracias, por adelantado.

Comment: No estoy muy familiarizado con `spring-boot`, pero parece que el último código está devolviendo toda la entidad... ¿podría ser que las queries adicionales se hicieran al serializar? Igual puedes probar `BaseEntity b = genericService.findOne(request); Log.info("antes de devolver"); return b;` para ver si el mensaje de log aparece entre las queries (o poner un sleep suficientemente significativo).

Comment: "¿podría ser que las queries adicionales se hicieran al serializar?"
¿Por qué podría suceder esto?
¿Qué es lo que está sobrescribiendo la annotation Lazy?

Comment: No es que "sobreescriba". Si se accede a la propiedad `b` (para serializarla o para cualquier otra cosa), tendrá que hacer una query para obtener los datos si está dentro de la transacción, o fallar con un `LazyInitializationException` si está fuera de la transacción. La inicialización lazy solo **retrasa** la carga de los datos hasta que son requeridos, no la elimina.